# Customize bootstrap nav with css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created navigation in center with below code HTML and CSS code

`HTML Code`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-inner" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BUSINESS SOLUTIONS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PARTNERS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

`CSS code`

```
.navbar .nav, .navbar .nav > li { float:none; display:inline-block; *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */ *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */ vertical-align: top; }
.navbar-inner { text-align:center; }
```

It looks like this
[image]

But I was looking like `Home` on active and hover. How can I do that 
[image]

I was looking of small red underline when menu is selected and same thing when I hover mouse on it.

Comment: Can you please expand the explanation a little bit. Also the images are way too small. I can hardly see a redline, is that what you want ?

Comment: Yea Just need small red underline when menu is selected and same thing when I hover mouse on it.

Comment: You need two selectors in css `ul.nav li.active a` and `ul.nav li:hover a` and then set `text-decoration:underline;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

```
.nav li.active a,.nav li:hover a{
background:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;

}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/dpk6aa09/)

**Updated Code**

```
.nav li.active a span,.nav li:hover a span{
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    display:block
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/dpk6aa09/3/)**

Comment: That I have done already but I was looking underline just under the text not so much down and shorter than text like 50% and in center

Answer (score 0):

So with the code you have provided I did this. If you want to make any changes just let me know I will make the necessary changes. The key idea is to use:

```
border-bottom
```

and

```
li:hover
```

properties.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L7x85dp5/

Comment: That I have done already but I was looking underline just under the text not so much down and shorter than text like 50% and in center